# How to use Wix Style React components with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a project in typescript + react, I want to install wix-react components, And I have a lot of errors

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button  from 'wix-style-react/Button';

export class Greeter extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return (
          <Button onClick={() => console.log('thanks for clicking :)')}>
            Click me!
          </Button>
        )
    }
}
```

First error what i have is:
Could not find a declaration file for module 'wix-style-react/Button'. '/Users/../node_modules/wix-style-react/Button.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. 
Then i found @types/wix-style-react, Next error: jsx element type 'Button' does not have any construct or call signatures.
I do not know how to install, tell me the way

Comment: Someone can help?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/wix-style-react

Comment: Just as a general note - `import React from "react";` - doesn't need / want the `* as`

Answer (score 0):

You are now getting the types automatically as the library provides it.
https://github.com/wix/wix-style-react/blob/master/docs/FAQ/TYPES.MD

The package mentioned above is no longer maintained and no longer needed.